# what is "error": "unsupported_grant_type" in web Api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to achieve  user login
and logout using angularJS and web Api
But  the server always return badrequest (400)
exception

the error is coming from this bit of code

```
AuthApp.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {

   var  authServiceFactory = {};

    var _authentication =
        {
            isAuth: false,
            userName: ""
        };

    // this is the login function
    authServiceFactory.login = function (loginData) {
        var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
       // alert(data);
        $http.post('/token', data, {
            header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function (response) {
            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: response.userName });

            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;

            deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err) {
            // _logout();
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    authServiceFactory.logout = function ()
    {
        localStorageService.remove("authenticationData");
        _authentication.isAuth = false;
        _authentication.userName = "";

    }

    return authServiceFactory;
}]);
```

using postman to further  see the error
this appears

> {   "error": "unsupported_grant_type" }

Comment: At least do a web search for that error so you know what it means

Comment: unsupported_grant_type can mean a few things like grant_type (param in the form post data) is wrong or the username/password combination sent is wrong. Your code looks mostly good but I think it's 'headers' not 'header' in your $http.post config when specifying the 'Content-type'. Try running Fiddler or something to see the HTTP traffic and work out if  something is missing in your POST.

Comment: I still can find the error all what others are saying is  header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } not  header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/Json' }  which is definitely handle

and also this is not working header(s)